# PHP CodeIgniter change object array data value from database with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, foreach

How I can change value of objects array, which I got from `$this->db->query('My Query');` (result is Object). I tried use `foreach ($data->result() as $row)` - it is working fine, I can reach every variable, but I can't modify it by using "&" (`foreach ($data->result() as &$row)`) because of Error (php don't show it). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra variable.

```
$result = $data->result();
foreach ($result as &$row) {
 // enter code here
}
```

Comment: Okey, it works fine, but how then I can generate table from array ($result, which I modified)? How it is posible to edi object and then greate table from it?

Comment: I see, this is a different question. You should issue 'update' statements to the database in order to do this. Raffaele's way is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you are assuming that modifing the object you are editing also values in the database.

If that's the case, you should run a query to update data in the database

```
$result = $data->result();
foreach ($result as &$row) {
  $row->prop = 'new value';
  $this->db->set($row)->where('id',$row->id)->update('table_name');
}
```

==================== EDIT ====================

If you want to ignore date like `0000-00-00` you should set it to an empty string and then print out the table.

```
$result = $data->result();
foreach ($result as &$row) 
{
  if( $row->date == '0000-00-00')
      $row->date = '';
}
```

to print out a table you can use the HTML table class of Codeigniter passing the $result object.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/table.html

```
$this->load->library('table');
echo $this->table->generate($result);
```

Comment: Not really, I need to modify values which I got from database and then show them on table. Main problem is with Dates, because, if value was `null`, then Dates value in table comes `0000-00-00`, so I need somehow to ignore or change value of it.

Comment: I know this way of solving problem, but CodeIgniter's method `$this->table->generate($data);` wants Object type variable, not array I think.

Comment: You can pass both. Array or object from database result. BTW, here we are working with objects so that's what you are asking :D

Comment: From the documentation: "$this->table->generate()

Returns a string containing the generated table. Accepts an optional parameter which can be an array or a database result object."

Comment: I think no, because there is some problem, when I add Array on `$this->table->generate($result);`, whole table disappears (means, that there is error).

Comment: If you are using my example, you have to use $this->table->generate($result) after the foreach loop. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I done everything like you said (I also tried it before), but there is some error or problems with it. Also, there is no problem with table lib, because I made autoload of it (because in my system there is so many tables)

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, methods, that were offered don't work. I found solution, how to solve my problem:

```
<?php $result = $data->result_array();
 foreach($result as &$row)
{
    if($row['date'] == '0000-00-00')
    {
        $row['date'] = ' ';
    } 
$this->table->add_row($row['date'], $row['(other parameter)']...);
}
$this->table->set_template($template); 
echo $this->table->generate(); ?>
```